# How to add css class through jsp

Tags: java, css, jsp

I have element `<div id="contact">` and having `CSS`

```
#contact {
    background: url(../images/icon/contact.png) left top no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 29px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

I want to add css class to id contact dynamically through JSP.

Here is the css class that I want to add for `id=contact` dynamically through `JSP`.

```
#contact.active {
    background: url(../images/icon/active_contact.png) left top no-repeat !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the css is already defined, you just need to add the class to your `<div id="contact">` to apply CSS style.

**JQuery** using [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
$( "#contact" ).addClass( "active" );
```

Plain **Javascript**:

```
var el = document.getElementById('contact');
if(el) {
    // safe check if div has another class active
    el.className += el.className ? ' active' : 'active';
}
```

Comment: Can we do this using jsp code instead of using JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: *Can we do this using jsp code?* I guess you must go deeper into JSP, your question does not make sense at all but short answer is **NO**. `JSP` cannot be used to manipulate HTML data dynamically.